# Why cant my function get data from JSON File?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to practice the usage of JSON file and fining out how it works. I have a JSON file attached to my document and one function with the same name as my object in JSON file. How ever it must put the data on a div but it does not. This is my Code:

Json File:

```
myFunction([
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "jQuery Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JSON Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "AJAX Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "SQL Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "PHP Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "XML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
}
])
```

**JS Function:**

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("w3schools").innerHTML = out;
```

And here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLV9A/

Any idea to make it working?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Order. JSFiddle places the contents of the "Script" panel after other Resources. So, it's trying to call the `function` before it's defined. Placing the resource in the markup with the Script in the `<head>` can get the desired order: http://jsfiddle.net/2grS8/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you for your help. It's right. I would choose it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your JSON file isn't actually a JSON file. It's a javascript file with a function being called that also happens to contain the array of data. My best guess would be that you're loading in the "JSON file" first, then your other file second. Thus you're calling the function before it exists, causing an error and JS execution to stop. Change the order of loading for your scripts and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like I need to do more research on JSON. I thought it is a JSON file but it seems an array as you said.

Comment: @user3763725 The W3Schools file appears to be [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/), which is a kind of hybrid of JSON and JavaScript that takes advantage of their similar syntax.